# I'm just here for the hat bug

Tags: bug

I am pretty sure I have not met the requirements for this hat, yet it's in my inventory. Just thought I would pass that along.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was for me to individually collect 20 hats. I guess we can close this if your scenario is the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is "own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats"

You own a hat (e.g. Hero of Questions) and the entire site collectively has at least 20.

Wear your new hat with pride. You qualify.